# parent() is not working on live elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why but `.parent()` is not working on dynamically created elements.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znvHa/) displaying my problem. It calculates discount price on static element, not so much on created one.

```
$('.item-sizes .discount-percent').live('keydown', function () {
        var percentValue = $(this).val();
        var basePrice = $('.base-price', $(this).parent().parent()).val(); // Undefine on live elements, defined on static

        if (basePrice) {
            discountValue = basePrice - ((percentValue / 100) * basePrice);
            $('.discount-price', $(this).parent().parent()).val(discountValue);
        }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but please stop using `.live()`. It's been [deprecated for ages now](http://liveisdeprecated). Use event delegation with `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: The error may have to do with your HTML, which is not shown.

Comment: use on('click', selector_for_live_listening, handler) if still produced, return and update your question. live is deprecated.

Comment: @shabunc: No; `live()` still works.

Comment: @SLaks yes `.live()` still works but it's a bad API and it's a good idea to break the habit of using it.

Comment: @SLaks ~ which **deprecated** is. However, it also means that while *it still works*, it may (and most probably will be) removed in a future version, so *stop using it*. Besides, the way it works is ultimately bad practice, at least compared to how `delegate` natively does.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan: I'm not saying that he shouldn't switch to `.on()`; I'm saying that switching to `.on()` won't solve the problem.

Comment: @SLaks ~ oh, cool then. The way you worded it, I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan - Chances are high that that [version will be 1.9](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/), scheduled for release in early 2013. Pretty soon :)

Comment: Well AFAIK `.on()` nor `.delegate()` does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/pfSnB/

Comment: Instead of `.parent().parent()` try using [`.closest(some-selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)

Comment: If people would stop posting about fixing things that don't need to be fixed to answer the question, these long pointless arguments that we all agree on wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `base-price` class on the wrong element:

```
<input type="text" name="text[]" placeholder="foo" class="span3 base-price"/>
```

which explains the `NaN` response

here it is fixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/znvHa/5/

Answer (score 4):

The HTML you're **adding** doesn't have a `base-price` class anywhere.

Comment: Yes it has. `<input type="text" name="baseprice[]" placeholder="price" class="span3 base-price">` Otherwise it would not work on static element.

Comment: @Qmal it does not in the fiddle. `<input type="text" name="baseprice[]" placeholder="price" class="span3"/>`

Comment: @Qmal the big string that adds the content is missing the class.